# Why can't the U.S. stop drug production in Afghanistan?

Tags: united-states, geopolitics, drugs, afghanistan, war-on-drugs

Since the U.S. invasion in 2001 opium fields have grown rapidly. Why has the U.S. not done anything about it? In previous times the U.S. rather successfully suppressed traffic in Latin America. But in Afghanistan - no.

One of [sources claiming that U.S. is just doing business](https://www.globalresearch.ca/drug-war-american-troops-are-protecting-afghan-opium-u-s-occupation-leads-to-all-time-high-heroin-production/5358053).

There is also a plethora of sources about U.S. fighting for freedom and peace, like BBC. In fact, there are many source from both sides.

So, what's going on with it? And please no answers in style "democracy installing is in progress". It continues too long (17 years in fact), to answer so. Really too long for any foreign country building.

For example they can build factories/other facilities to change GDP from drugs to goods, why don't they want to do it?

Comment: There is a section in an wikipedia article about this that might answer your exact question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_production_in_Afghanistan#Afghan_War_%282001-current%29 . I'm sure someone will basically copy-paste it later to create a high-upvote answer if you would like to read it in an SE format, but there you go

Comment: I have read it, but there is no answers in fact. There is just constatation: yes, it is growing. And sentences about "freedom in progress".

Comment: Yeah, here are some smart guys, which like one-side answers

Comment: "While U.S. and allied efforts to combat the drug trade have been stepped up, the effort is hampered by the fact that many suspected drug traffickers are now top officials in the Karzai government"  "52% of the nation's GDP ..  is generated by the drug trade" " sale of poppies constitutes the livelihood of Afghanistan's rural farmers." I don't know how you come to the conclusion that the article is about freedom in progress. If you do not trust the article, at least include a statement in your question that you are aware of "popular reasons given" and say why you don't believe them

Comment: Hmm. maybe article is mistranslated for me. But will left edits - it is just another question why - it is enough time to build factories/something other to change GDP from drugs to goods

Comment: @Alexei, thanks, still do no know how to make links short

Comment: In this case, your question isn't why they haven't stopped the drug production but why they haven't turned Afghanistan into a major economic powerhouse that doesn't rely on agriculture anymore (what happens to those farmers?) like they apparently did with Latin America with the nice side effect that the drugs stop? I think this isn't well reflected in your question currently.

Comment: Hah, right you are. Will edit question further.

Comment: I think it is just one of ways to do it - to stop drug production, change its value in GDP

Comment: Now edited and expanded my answer substantially to explain how your perceived lack of executive will in achieving a total control on opium cultivation in Afghanistan strongly suggests that the "war on drugs" is currently a lesser priority for USA than the War Against Terror, please see @user2501323.

Comment: `For example they can build factories/other facilites to change GDP from drugs to goods, why they do not want to do it?` Factories do not grow from the ground. You need infrastructure, educated people, stability to ensure that your investment is not razed in the next attack. You need raw materials and a product to produce (although with low enough wages you could create sweatshops). Your question implies that all that they need is "wanting" to...

Comment: The have 17 years to do all the stuff, but they do just nothing. There is no strategy to fighting drugs, if not worse.

Infrastructure, educated people? 17 years is more than enough to build schools and educate people. Even in war conditions.

Comment: "In previous times U.S. rather successfully suppressed traffic in Latin America" = citation?

Comment: Not a citation, just my english.) Some time ago read about it, do not remember where

Comment: @user2501323 I remember reading it also and thinking with myself "what a load of BS" so citation needed

Comment: Really, if you remember - give the source, I'll make citation. I myself do not remember, that was a while ago.

Comment: @user2501323 - what Blip was saying was, you're making it sound like it's a fact. It's not a fact unless you can cite some proof of that.

Comment: Hmm. I thought that was obvious. Can U.S. win just one drug war or not?) Okay, will search for sources)

Comment: The US could have easily bankrupted the entire drug underworld by legalizing drugs within their own country and inspiring the rest of the world to do the same. So you can ask a broader question - why don't they want to rid the world of the biggest source of illegal incomes?

Comment: Hah) If you have water on the floor in your room, you can make floor dry, or you can say "okay, I'll know live in a wet, watered room". I don't think, that second way is a decision)

Comment: "The have 17 years to do all the stuff, but they do just nothing. There is no strategy to fighting drugs, if not worse. Infrastructure, educated people? 17 years is more than enough to build schools and educate people. " - In the West, you're considered to have left education early if you leave before you're 18 years old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the very few good things the Taliban did while in charge of Afghanistan was crack down on opium farming as an immoral activity. However, one has to contrast that against the many bad things they did, such as executions on flimsy premises, destruction of ancient cultural artifacts, and providing a base of operations for Al Qaida, from which they launched the African embassy attacks, the USS Cole attack, and the 9/11 attacks.

One of the unfortunate side effects of deposing the Taliban was the resumption of opium farming. The coalition forces that are in Afghanistan right now have their hands full trying to deal with a resurgent Taliban presence. The current Afghan government is either incapable of, or possibly unwilling to, interrupt opium farming.

Afghanistan is a poor country. Any income is a very dear thing to the residents. Opium happens to be a fairly lucrative cash crop. To them, it's not selling poison, it's feeding their families. Doesn't work out that way when the product reaches the final consumer, but the addicts are continents away, while the farmer's family is right in front of them. Which brings up another unpleasant choice... crack down on opium farming while not offering any alternative, and the tribes turn against you. Afghanistan in decades past, and Vietnam, show what happens when the endemic population of a country turns against an occupying force.

So, rather than conspiracy theories about the US promoting opium growth, what we really have is a no win choice. Leave the Taliban in place and get more terrorist attacks. Knock them out, and as a side effect, opium production resumes, and probably will remain in production until Afghanistan has a stable government willing to choke off the opium farming by offering a viable income alternative.

Unfortunately, Afghanistan hasn't really had a stable government in all of history... it has always been, and probably always will be, a collection of regional tribes.

Comment: In addition the price of opium at the farm gate is around $200/kilo, but in the USA around $16,000/kilo. So the farm gate price could increase by a factor of 10 before it started to seriously dent the profits from the rest of the trade. This makes the replacement of opium farming by other trades a difficult economic proposition.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is extremely relevant and I was very surprised that nobody asked it earlier on Politics.SE: I was curious myself a month back, but didn't have to ask here because I got my answers from the very comprehensive [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_production_in_Afghanistan) on this topic, which starts thusly:

> Opium production in Afghanistan has been on the rise since U.S. occupation started in 2001. Afghanistan's opium poppy production goes into more than 90% of heroin worldwide. Afghanistan has been the world's greatest illicit opium producer (...) Afghanistan is the main producer of opium in the "Golden Crescent". Based on UNODC data, opium poppy cultivation was more in each of the growing seasons in the periods between 2004 and 2007 than in any one year during Taliban rule. More land is now used for opium in Afghanistan than is used for coca cultivation in Latin America. In 2007, 93% of the non-pharmaceutical-grade opiates on the world market originated in Afghanistan. This amounts to an export value of about $4 billion, with a quarter being earned by opium farmers and the rest going to district officials, insurgents, warlords, and drug traffickers.

The most important point [quoted](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_production_in_Afghanistan#Counter-narcotics_policy) there, which answers your original question in a nutshell, is that [the Afghan economy is so heavily dependent on opium cultivation that]

> the poppy eradication campaign (...) could well give the Taliban the decisive advantage in their struggle for the hearts and minds of the Afghan people.

In short, strictly enforcing the anti-opium policy will drive the people into the camp of the Taliban, and USA cannot take such a risk which would greatly "strengthen the enemy" in the war against terror.

Addressing your "why can't they build factories/other facilites to change GDP from drugs to goods" edit to the Q, the logical short answer is that ***USA still does not have sufficient political or military control in most of the opium growing areas*** (or else why the war on terror continues?), and I am trying to find references to support this point.

Many articles on this topic, including the above referenced Wikipedia article, also suggest that the opium trade is mainly controlled by the same Afghan warlords whose support USA needs in the ongoing war against fundamentalist terrorism. Moreover a huge number of local farmers depend on opium for the subsistence of their families. If **cracking down heavily on the opium industry will have the effect of antagonizing these warlords and alienating the common people** then USA will not be able to stabilize Afghanistan beyond the influence of socially retrograde and violently fundamentalist forces, and the Taliban can make a comeback by exploiting popular anti-US sentiments that might result from a strong campaign against opium. Nor can the opium trade even be controlled effectively if the Americans lose the support of the warlords and the common people.

Your perceived lack of executive will in achieving a total control on opium cultivation in Afghanistan thus strongly suggests that the "war on drugs" is currently a lesser priority for USA than the War Against Terror.

Comment: For 17 years they can do even "softly" policy, but nothing we can see. NO policy in fact. And I doubt that Taliban can make terror actions out of Afghanistan - they are on their land

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your "build factories/other facilites to change GDP from drugs to goods" edit @user2501323; the logical short answer is that ***USA still does not have sufficient political or military control in most of the opium growing areas*** (or else why the war on terror continues?), but I am trying to find proper references to support this point.

Comment: You are most welcome @user2501323. Please see this answer once in a while for edits to provide better references.

Comment: appreciate your changes, waiting for another answers to compare with

Comment: OK fine, thanks for asking this important question @user2501323.

Comment: Re "why can't they build factories/other facilites to change GDP from drugs to goods": Put yourself in the place of a farmer.  You can stay on your land, and grow a profitable crop, or you can go work in a damned factory for subsistence wages.  Which would you choose?

Comment: This answer as written seems implausible -- it would be better if it offered a more international historical perspective on what correlations exist between risk-averse occupying forces and bribe seeking occupying forces, (assuming there's any difference), and the business of opium farming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @agc. Being averse to any risk that needlessly endangers the priority mission is characteristic of *all* occupying forces. The only historical exception was the Nazis relentlessly pursuing the Final Solution even at risk of losing the war, which they did end up losing. It is clear from the ongoing opium trade that the War on Drugs is not USA's top priority in Aghanistan. I shall try to incorporate your recommended element into my final answer.

Comment: Well there's *the* priority mission, as in what the folks back home are told, and the *de facto* mission.  Suppose an occupation's managers find that being a middleman or virtual taxer of contraband was a more rewarding employment that any likely post-victory prospect.

Comment: [Macaulay on Machiaveli](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/mod/1850Macaulay-machiavelli.asp):  *"...Left to the conduct of men who neither loved those whom they defended, nor hated those whom they opposed, who were often bound by stronger ties to the army against which they fought than to the State which they served, who lost by the termination of the conflict, and gained by its prolongation, war completely changed its character."*

Comment: Many thanks for the link. The subversion of the "great aim" is highly possible as history suggests, but where could we get supporting references @agc?

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that Afghanistan is backward and that the USA is advanced and, moreover, that the difference is about 300 years.

The only way that the US could change Afghanistan in the way you suggest would take a continuous effort of 100 years. This would include the creation of an educated  workforce of men and women, and the creation and establishment of the institutions required by a modern economy: rule of law, mature laws of contract, mature laws of intellectual property and real estate. Independent judiciary, honest well-paid police force. a military that is proud of is subjection to civilian rule.

All that in only 100 years. Not bad going.

But if that sounds like the US re-creating Afgahanistan in its own image the ask yourself what else could it do?

You don't have to answer because it's a pipe dream.  If Afghanistan is not a wreckage in 100 years it will be because Cina sat on it and recreated it in its own authoritarian image.

Comment: Perhaps instead of Afghanistan being backward, the USA is merely [obliviously self-congratulatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Man%27s_Burden).